# SonarQube multi module maven project

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have the following structure for a maven project:

```
sonar-project.properties
Jenkinsfile
parent
->parent
->->pom.xml
->module1
->->pom.xml
->module2
->->pom.xml
->module3
->->pom.xml
```

pom parent:

```
<modules>
    <module>../module1</module>
    <module>../module2</module>
    <module>../module3</module>
</modules>
```

sonar-project.properties :

```
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.projectKey=com.company.project:parent

#List of module identifiers
sonar.modules=../module1,../module2,../module3

#module1 settings
module1.sonar.projectName=com.company.project:module1
module1.sonar.sources=src/main/java

#module2 settings
module2.sonar.projectName=com.company.project:module2
module2.sonar.sources=src/main/java

#module3 settings
module3.sonar.projectName=com.company.project:module3
module3.sonar.sources=src/main/java
```

My Jenkins pipeline is :

```
steps {
    script {
        dir('parent') {
            withSonarQubeEnv('SONAR') {
                sh "sonar-scanner -Dproject.settings=../sonar-project.properties -Dsonar.version=${params.buildVersion} -Dsonar.projectVersion=${params.projectVersion}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have this error:

```
ERROR: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'com.company.project:parent:../module1': sonar.sources
```

Comment: First change your project structure and make the parent the root of your project and all modules childs of it. Second I strongly suggest to use the [sonar-maven-plugin](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin) that makes the whole configuration easier... (you can omit the sonar-project.properties completely) ... Having a parent which contains `<module>../module..</module>` is a smell...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have missed to add two mandatory sonar analysis properties.

Those two are: `-Dsonar.sources=src` and `-Dsonar.java.binaries=**/*`

You can mention both the properties in the Jenkins step like

```
sh "sonar-scanner -Dproject.settings=../sonar-project.properties -Dsonar.version=${params.buildVersion} -Dsonar.projectVersion=${params.projectVersion} -Dsonar.sources=src -Dsonar.java.binaries=**/*"
```

Or

You can include them in `sonar-project.properties` like

```
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.projectKey=com.company.project:parent
sonar.sources=src
sonar.java.binaries=**/*

#List of module identifiers
sonar.modules=../module1,../module2,../module3

#module1 settings
module1.sonar.projectName=com.company.project:module1
module1.sonar.sources=src/main/java

#module2 settings
module2.sonar.projectName=com.company.project:module2
module2.sonar.sources=src/main/java

#module3 settings
module3.sonar.projectName=com.company.project:module3
module3.sonar.sources=src/main/java
```

> Note: `sonar.java.binaries` is important for analysis of maven projects.